# Cannot install Xcode Command Line tools over a corporate proxy

Tags: xcode, bash, terminal, xcode-command-line-tools

I'm having trouble running the following command in the Terminal:

`xcode-select --install`

After agreeing to the T&Cs, I get the following error pop up:

[image: Can't download the software because of a network problem.]

> Can't download the software because of a network problem.

As I am behind a corporate proxy for the company I work for, I've correctly set this up on my Mac in System Preferences and I can browse the web normally. I also added the proxy settings via these commands that I was given (real URL removed):

`export http_proxy="http://example.net:80"`

`export https_proxy="$http_proxy"`

I tried following [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3i7eqy/cant_download_the_software_because_of_a_network/), which suggested deleting App Store preference files, but that didn't work.

I'm a bit lost now because I don't know how else to approach the issue. Perhaps there is something around installing things via the Terminal that I don't know of, in relation to proxy settings?

Answer (score 3):

Xcode's Command Line Tools can be downloaded directly from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changesץ